# How to wait for a successful response in Cypress tests

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing

**Background**

I use 3 back-end servers to provide fault tolerance for one of my online SaaS application. All important API calls, such as getting user data, contact all 3 servers and use value of first successfully resolved response, if any.

```js
export function getSuccessValueOrThrow$<T>(
        observables$: Observable<T>[],
        tryUntilMillies = 30000,
    ): Observable<T> {
        return race(
            ...observables$.map(observable$ => {
                return observable$.pipe(
                    timeout(tryUntilMillies),
                    catchError(err => {
                        return of(err).pipe(delay(5000), mergeMap(_err => throwError(_err)));
                    }),
                );
            })
        );
    }
```

getSuccessValueOrThrow$ get called as following:

```js
const shuffledApiDomainList = ['server1-domain', 'server2-domain', 'server3-domain';
const sessionInfo = await RequestUtils.getSuccessValueOrThrow(
                        ...(shuffledApiDomainList.map(shuffledDomain => this.http.get<SessionDetails>(`${shuffledDomain}/file/converter/comm/session/info`))),
                    ).toPromise();
```

Note: if one request resolve faster than others, usually the case, `race` rxjs function will cancel the other two requests. On Chrome dev network tab it will look like bellow where first request sent out was cancelled due to being too slow.

[image]

**Question:**

I use **/file/converter/comm/session/info** (lets call it Endpoint 1) to get some data related to a user. This request dispatched to all 3 back-end servers. If one resolve, then remaining 2 request will be cancelled, i.e. they will return null.

On my Cypress E2E test I have

```js
cy.route('GET', '/file/converter/comm/session/info').as('getSessionInfo');
cy.visit('https://www.ps2pdf.com/compress-mp4');
cy.wait('@getSessionInfo').its('status').should('eq', 200)
```

This sometimes fails if the  since getSessionInfo alias was hooked on to a request that ultimately get cancelled by `getSuccessValueOrThrow$` because it wasn't the request that succeeded.Bellow image shows how 1 out of 3 request aliased with getSessionInfo succeeded but the test failed since the first request failed.

[image]

**In Cypress, how do I wait for a successful i.e. status = 200 request?**

Answer (score 3):

**Approach 1**

Use `.should()` callback and repeat the `cy.wait` call if status was not 200:

```
function waitFor200(routeAlias, retries = 2) {
  cy.wait(routeAlias).then(xhr => {
    if (xhr.status === 200) return // OK
    else if (retries > 0) waitFor200(routeAlias, retries - 1); // wait for the next response
    else throw "All requests returned non-200 response";
  })
}

// Usage example.
// Note that no assertions are chained here,
// the check has been performed inside this function already.
waitFor200('@getSessionInfo'); 

// Proceed with your test
cy.get('button').click(); // ...
```

**Approach 2**

Revise what it is that you want to test in the first place.
Chances are - there is something on the page that tells the user about a successful operation. E.g. show/hide a spinner or a progress bar, or just that the page content is updated to show new data fetched from the backend.

So in this approach you would remove `cy.wait()` altogether, and focus on what the user sees on the page - do some assertions on the actual page content.

Answer (score 2):

[`cy.wait()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait.html#Arguments) yields an object containing the HTTP request and response properties of the XHR. The error you're getting is because you're looking for property `status` in the XHR object, but it is a property of the Response Object. You first have to get to the Response Object:

```
cy.wait('@getSessionInfo').should(xhr => {
    expect(xhr.response).to.have.property('status', 200);
});
```

---

Edit: Since our backend uses graphql, all calls use the single `/graphql` endpoint. So I had to come up with a solution to differentiate each call.

I did that by using the `onResponse()` method of `cy.route()` and accumulating the data in Cypress [environment](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables.html#Setting) object:

```
cy.route({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/file/converter/comm/session/info',
  onResponse(xhr) {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      Cypress.env('sessionInfo200') = xhr;
    }
  }
})
```

You can then use it like this:

```
cy.wrap(Cypress.env()).should('have.property', 'sessionInfo200');
```

Comment: According to the documentation its looks like the xhr object has the status property https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait.html#Wait-for-a-specific-XHR-to-respond. By the way, question is not related to how I get the status. the issue is that it only fails sometimes as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: You're right, I read too fast. See my edited answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I wait like this:

```
const isOk = cy.wait("@getSessionInfo").then((xhr) => {
  return (xhr.status === 200);
});
```