# how to find article with status code 200 using cypress instead of 307 or some other one

Tags: cypress

I'm trying cypress API Intercepting and I have an error because website gives me multiple URL calls with the same name 'articles' and one are having status code 307 and the otherone has 200. how to find the article with status code 200?

Here is my code

```js
it('should logged in',()=> {
cy.wait(3000)
cy.contains('New Article').click()
cy.get('fieldset').then(article =>{
    cy.server()
    cy.route('POST', '**/articles').as('postArticles')         
    cy.wrap(article).find('[placeholder="Article Title"]').type('New Article')
    cy.wrap(article).eq(2).type('nothing')
    cy.wrap(article).eq(3).type('some text')
    cy.wrap(article).find('button').contains(' Publish Article ').click()
    cy.contains('Home').click()
    cy.wait('@postArticles')
        cy.get('@postArticles').then(xhr =>{
        console.log(xhr)
        expect(xhr.status).to.equal(200)
        expect(xhr.request.body.article.body).to.equal('some text')
        expect(xhr.request.body.article.description).to.equal('nothing')
        expect(xhr.request.body.article.title).to.equal('New Article')
    })
})
})
```

})

[image: this is the website network image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an answer here that looks like it will work

[How to wait for a successful response in Cypress tests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61722444/16997707)

```js
function waitFor200(routeAlias, retries = 2) {  // bump up retries to suit your test
  cy.wait(routeAlias).then(xhr => {
    if (xhr.status === 200) return // OK
    else if (retries > 0) waitFor200(routeAlias, retries - 1); // wait for the next response
    else throw "All requests returned non-200 response";
  })
}

waitFor200('@getSessionInfo'); 

// Proceed with your test
cy.get('button').click(); // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cy.get('@postArticles.all)` when using `cy.intercept()`, not sure about `cy.route()` but you should switch to the new version.

Ref [Asserting Network Calls from Cypress Tests](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/12/23/asserting-network-calls-from-cypress-tests/)

```js
cy.contains('Home').click()

cy.wait('@postArticles')   // only waits the first call!

cy.contains('Global Feed')  // wait for something indicating the POSTs have finished

cy.get('@postArticles.all').then(xhrs => {

  expect(xhrs.map(xhr => xhr.status)).to.include(200)       // one of them is "200"

  const twoHundred = xhrs.find(xhr => xhr.status === 200)  // get it

  expect(twoHundred.body.article.body).to.equal('some text')
  expect(twoHundred.body.article.description).to.equal('nothing')
  expect(twoHundred.body.article.title).to.equal('New Article')
})
```